# Task threads and Azure CloudBlobClient

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I've been working on this a couple of days now and have read the previous questions regarding multiple threads and blob clients and implemented their suggestions.

I've distilled the problem down to the below.

No errors are generated, just nothing is written to the *threadtest* container (which already exists). Sometimes one blob gets written and then nothing.

If I increase the Sleep to 1 second everything is fine.

The reason for the code is to benchmark Azure's blob writing capabilities. (I have currently got 8 single threaded instances doing 700,000 an hour but I'm sure I can get that higher if I could figure this out)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThreadedWriterTest
{
    public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {
        private static CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;

        public override void Run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> writeStuff());
            }
        }

        private void writeStuff()
        {
            CloudBlobClient threadClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            threadClient.GetBlobReference("threadtest/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).UploadText("Hello " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }



        public override bool OnStart()
        {
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;
            storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("XXX"));
            return base.OnStart();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I just call `writeStuff()` directly in the while loop it works.

Comment: If the writes take longer than 10ms on average then you'll end up with a whole lot of `Task`s waiting. Perhaps that's your problem - is your VM pegged on CPU or memory? You might be better off starting one thread per available connection, and having each thread write in a tight loop. Or, even better, use the async writing methods with some mechanism to control outstanding requests.

Comment: You're spot on. This code generated too many concurrent threads, I have used a semaphore to limit the number and will be posting a solution soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code generated too many concurrent threads, my naive approach of throttling with `Thread.Sleep()` was not enough to limit the thread count.

Introducing a semaphore (basically a mechanism for counting how many threads are executing concurrently) solved the problem dramatically. I am steadily increasing the concurrency limit and instance count and am already over 1 million an hour. (The actual code generates random length data 16-32K with the odd one ~4MB - 4 instances with 10 concurrent threads)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThreadedWriterTest
{
    public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {
        private static CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
        private static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(3, 3);

        public override void Run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                semaphore.WaitOne();
                Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> writeStuff());
            }
        }

        private void writeStuff()
        {
            CloudBlobClient threadClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            threadClient.GetBlobReference("threadtest/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).UploadText("Hello " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            semaphore.Release();
        }



        public override bool OnStart()
        {
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;
            storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("XXX"));
            return base.OnStart();
        }
    }
}
```